# How to fade the background-image to black with CSS?

Tags: css

I want to have a background-image which is not repeated. When the image ends, it should softly fade to black.

Here is an example of what I mean, it just misses the "soft fading". The image ends abrupt and there is black, I would like to have this transition more smooth. Is that possible?

(image randomly taken from google)

```
body {
    background:url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png) #000 no-repeat;
}
```

Live-Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sMc8a/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using this code. http://jsfiddle.net/sMc8a/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="example">
    Hello
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: black;
}
.example {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
    ),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
    ),
    url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);

  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
    ),
    -moz-linear-gradient(left, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
    ),
    url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);

  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
    ),
    -o-linear-gradient(left, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
    ),
    url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);

  background-image: linear-gradient(top, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(left, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
    ),
    url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);
}
```

Comment: You could stop hating an provide a better answer too.

Comment: This doesn't work, tested in Firefox 24. I tried to remove the "-webkit-" prefixes, still not functional.

Comment: Ok I'll provide a fix, just a moment

Comment: No problem!  Thanks for choosing it as answer!

Answer (score 5):

This works in all *major* browsers, test it out!

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sMc8a/5/)

```
.background {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 1) 100%), url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);
background-image:  -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 1) 100%), url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);
background-image:  -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 1) 100%), url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);
background-image:  -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 1) 100%), url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);
background-image:  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 1) 100%), url(http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png);
}
```

I included the -ms- prefix.. But I don't really think it's necessary.

As I said this only works in the major browsers.. therefore add a fallback such as:

```
background: url('http://www.stadtteilschule-oejendorf.de/Unterricht/files/stacks_image_2936.png');
```

Comment: The latest versions of all the major browsers support the standard syntax.  IE9 doesn't understand gradients, even with the prefix, so you don't gain anything by including it.

Comment: What i'm saying is, the vendor prefixes aren't needed by any of the major browsers anymore.  You could get rid of the other 4 lines and reduce the CSS to just the standard `linear-gradient`, and only the like 3 people still running old versions of FF or Opera would ever notice.  (I never use the prefixes anyway, for the same reason i don't use conditional comments or JavaScript-not-ECMAScript features.)  You'd just have to include a single background as a fallback, as you were talking about.